# parent window open child window

Tags: javascript, jsp

I want a page that open child window. The child window will be redirect to other website for processing. The other website will send the result to our server by redirect on the child window.our server will process the result and return to parent window and close the child window. Can it be done and how?

Comment: What have you tried?
StackOverflow is not a code factory. We'll gladly help, provided you've put some effort into it, first.

Answer (score 7):

1. You use [window.open](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/window.open) method to open a child window and store the returned reference to interact with it later.
2. You use the [window.parent](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/window.parent) property from the child window to access the parent window.

[Here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/25388/Accessing-parent-window-from-child-window-or-vice) is an article demonstrating the approach.